# Ansible action module with FQCN task name

Tags: ansible

How should action plugins be named when they are trying to override a task that is called by the FQCN in ansible?

Currently if we put a plugin into the `action_plugins` directory, named the same as the task, it gets picked up and called.
If the same task is changed to use the FQCN, the task executor never calls the action plugin because it isn't in the commands collection. This results it is reverting back to the `normal` plugin https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/86b86398f0e0c61df615d1fcf7643f01a1084327/lib/ansible/executor/task_executor.py#L1120. This is meant to be only for [plugins that do not already have a plugin assigned](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/action.html).

I've tried having the plugin called the FQCN name inside of the `action_plugins` directory, and creating subdirectories in there too matching the name, neither have worked.

Example we have `plugins/action/jira.py` which intercepts `jira` command calls and works correctly. If the users playbook calls `community.general.jira` instead, we can't intercept the calls.

Comment: Propose a PR to the community.general collection to integrate your action plugin. Else make your own collection with your action and module.

Comment: Our actions aren't suitable for upstream inclusion, we do things like inject auth information and guard certain functions for our setup. Similarly duplicating community plugins to our own namespace to achieve something which is possibly without FQCNs seems, well insane.

Comment: Keep your action plugin, possibly in a collection, call it `[my.collection.]custom_jira`. Call the `community.general.jira` module from your plugin once your are done with the local stuff so you don't have to duplicate it. Have your user switch their call for their tasks in their playbook to your action plugin. It would be totally insane and catastrophic if you could transparently change the behavior of a call to a module without anyone noticing (which seems to still be possible with the short name in your above example and is absolutely scary).